# Mongodb admin data losing changes randomly

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ubuntu

I am very confused, I make changes to my admin db in mongo, but when i come back, a day maybe 2 days. All of these have disappeared. I have not knowingly made any changes to the db, nor have I even used mongo at all in this time.

I check if I have any users:

```
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.getUsers();
[ ]
```

So I than add a user to `users`

```
db.createUser( { user: "root", pwd: "XXX", roles: [ "root" ] })
```

I then confirm the user is added:

```
> db.getUsers();
[
    {
        "_id" : "admin.root",
        "user" : "root",
        "db" : "admin",
        "roles" : [
            {
                "role" : "root",
                "db" : "admin"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

So am I able to edit the root users or even the `db users` from inside my normal node app? I wouldn't have thought so?

Comment: Someone posted something very similar within the last day. This makes me suspect your password is not as secure as you might think.

Comment: Interesting, so its not normally, its happened a good few times to me... Indeed then i will try a new password

Comment: Just looking for the post now. But pretty much the same thing, credentials changed and data lost. You aren't possibly running in a docker container or similar container format? Those could be an explanation for reversion, but the other usual reason for inexplicable loss is that someone is tampering.